# jQuery.each(values, function(i,v){ ... }) Why v is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have several textboxes which I need to check before post them back. I do this with jQuery using each function. When the submit button is pressed (LinkButton1) I iterate over the textboxes and check they values:

```
<asp:textbox id="txt1" class="tocheck" runat="server />
<asp:textbox id="txt2" class="tocheck" runat="server />
<asp:textbox id="txt3" class="tocheck" runat="server />

$('#LinkButton1').click(function () {
    var error = false;
    $.each('.tocheck', function (i, v) {
        checkVal(v.val());
    });
});
```

But a runtime error is thrown saying v is undefined:

[image]

How can I retrieve the textbox value?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough HTML source. Your `each` iterates through `.text`, which I cannot see in your source code?

Comment: I was mistaken typing the code, text means toeach. Post updated.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? With jQuery 1.7.1, it parses `'.tocheck'`as an array of letters (i = 0 -> v = '.', i = 1 -> v = 't'...). You have an `$` missing perhaps?

Comment: Dont be confuse with $().each() and $.each()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't passing in a collection correctly.

```
$('#LinkButton1').click(function () {
    var error = false;
    $.each('.text', function (i, v) { // <-- you are passing in a STRING not a collection of elements
        checkVal(v.val());
    });
});
```

try

```
$('#LinkButton1').click(function () {
    var error = false;
    $.each($('.text'), function (i, v) {
        checkVal($(v).val());// <-- need to wrap in jQuery to use jQuery methods
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the solution I came up with as well.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to pass in `v` - remove it.

And use `$(this)` instead.

I.E

```
$('#LinkButton1').click(function () {
    var error = false;
    $('.tocheck').each( function () {
        checkVal($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: @Downvoter...Please say why, rather than run down the page clicking down arrows..

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer, but I don't see why exactly you need to jQuery-wrap `this` here. `checkVal(this.value)` should suffice.

Comment: The reason $(this) works is because .each runs the function passed in as an argument in the context of the current DOM element of the matching selector. The this keyword is wrapped because without it then it is just a DOM element, but passing it into the $() allows you to have access to jquery methods, such as $(this).text().

Comment: @raina77ow - yep, that's fine too. Just the way I always did it - Learned something new now though :) Thanks.

Comment: where is the 'toEach' class? I thought it was 'tocheck'?

Comment: :) where is the 'text' class?

Comment: i hadn't refreshed his edit. I remembered seeing it go from .text to .toeach - then made my boo boo, now it's all good again.

Answer (score 3):

you got a error in the class selector. change it to

```
$(".tocheck").each(function(i, v){
    checkVal($(v).val());
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly

```
$.each('.tocheck', function (i, v) {
        checkVal(v.val());
    });
```

supposed to be either

```
$('.tocheck').each(function (i, v) {
        checkVal(v.value);
});
```

'
    **OR**
/

```
 $.each( $('.tocheck'), function (i, v) {
            checkVal(v.value);
        });
```

Secondly  **v** here is the **DOM object** and you are trying to use **jQuery method** on it .. That's the reason for the error..

So `v.val()`

supposed to be

`v.value`   **OR**  `$(v).val();` **OR**  `this.value`   **OR**  `$(this).val();`

Comment: But I think you might be upto a different problem completely .. Because of the postback which occurs when you click the link , mostly your textbox values are being reset back to default

Answer (score 1):

The `$.each` function designed for mostly value arrays like intergers or string that s why v is value not item. so you should use each jQuery array as below.

```
$(".tocheck").each(function (index, item)
{
   alert($(item).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tocheck').each( function () {
        checkVal($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: I didn't down vote you but I am guessing that the reason they did was because the class text is not in the scope of the question, so your answer does not really illustrate how to solve the problem in a manner that the questioner can readily use, especially if they are a confused by the syntax as is.

Comment: According to the questioner: class name was just a mistype. Problems were with using $.each instead of $.prototype.each and v.val() instead of $(this).val(). Anyhow, I believe everyone should always explain downvotes. :)

Comment: I agree with what you are saying.